# Change color of link inside span class

Tags: html, css, class, hyperlink, colors

I have:

```
<span class="field-content highlight-front">
   <a href="/node/42" hreflang="en">This is an example</a>
</span>
```

in the css file i want to change the color of the link by using the span class.

```
.highlight-front{ 
   color: blue;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions or places to read about targeting a link through a span class?

Comment: `.highlight-front a { 
   color: blue;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify element inside span for colouring, which means adding `a` after your class name (child of span):

Use this:

```
.highlight-front a{ 
   color: blue;
}
```

See here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Tn3IomLmUaobN59Cdg4j?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

add `.highlight-front a{` in the class to specify all `a` tags inside `span` with class `highlight-front`

```css
.highlight-front a{ 
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="field-content highlight-front">
   <a href="/node/42" hreflang="en">This is an example</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can also try this
<span class="field-content">
   <a class="highlight-front" href="/node/42" hreflang="en">This is an example</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this by the following:

```
<span class="field-content highlight-front">
    <a href="/node/42" hreflang="en">This is an example</a>
</span>

.highlight-front a{ 
    color: blue; 
 }
```

Which will colour any `<a>` found as a decendent of the `.highlight-front` class.